# Delete duplicated object from array if key is available

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tested everything I knew and I searched, but nothing worked.
I have an array, this array contains flexible objects.

```
let filter = [
    { key1: "stringReq" },
    { key1: "1" },
    { key1: "2" },
    { key1: "3" },
    { key1: "someString" },
    { key2: "stringReq" },
    { key2: "5" },
    { key2: "6" },
    { key2: "7" },
    { key3: "string" }
];
```

Now I want an array with object like this.

```
let filter = [
    { key1: "stringReq" },
    { key2: "stringReq" },
    { key3: "string" }
];
```

I want only one of the keys in the array. This was an example in my code, I don't have any information of keys or values is a variable array with data.

Comment: The general solution to all problems like this is to create an object whose keys are whatever field you want to make unique.

Comment: And to get the keys of an object, use `Object.keys()`. If it only has one property, use `Object.keys(obj)[0]` to get that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution returns the first occurrence of a key using a Set as the `thisArg` of `Array#filter()` to keep track of what was seen already

```js
let arr = [
{ key1: "stringReq" },
{ key1: "1" },
{ key1: "2" },
{ key1: "3" },
{ key1: "someString" },
{ key2: "stringReq" },
{ key2: "5" },
{ key2: "6" },
{ key2: "7" },
{ key3: "string" }
];

const res = arr.filter(function(o) {
   const [k] = Object.keys(o);
   return this.has(k) ? false : (this.add(k), true) ;
},new Set());

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you all for the fast answers. But the solution from works for me fine.

Comment: One question how difficulty is it if i want to check the value of the object and than filter?
example 'arr = [{key1: searchedValue}, {key1:1}, {key1: 2}, {key2: date}, {key2: date2}, {key3: "string"} ]' now i want an array with object with key1: searchedValue (this value i want to search), key2: date, key2: date2, key3.

Comment: @charlietfl I _really like_ your approach and believe it _should_ work. Unfortunately it does not work on my Android Chrome and returns all elements of `arr` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get the property value of the first time each particular key is found in an object. The following will return just that:

```js
let arr = [ { key1: "stringReq" }, { key1: "1" }, { key1: "2" }, { key1: "3" }, { key1: "someString" }, { key2: "stringReq" }, { key2: "5" }, { key2: "6" }, { key2: "7" }, { key3: "string" } ];

const res=Object.entries(arr.reduce((a,c)=>{
 let [[k,v]] = Object.entries(c);
 if(!a[k]) a[k]=v
 return a;
},{})).map(e=>Object.fromEntries([e]));

console.log(res);
```

Or, using @charlietfl's ingenuous `thisArg` trick:

```js
let arr = [ { key1: "stringReq" }, { key1: "1" }, { key1: "2" }, { key1: "3" }, { key1: "someString" }, { key2: "stringReq" }, { key2: "5" }, { key2: "6" }, { key2: "7" }, { key3: "string" } ];

const res = arr.filter(function(o) { 
const [k] = Object.keys(o); 
return this[k] ? false : this[k]=1; 
},{}); 


console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you  for the solution, it's works but here i get a object and i need a array.

Comment: Yep - I added an `Object.entries()` and an `Object.fromEntries()`. Now it returns an array.

Comment: Nice, it's works fine, thank you. Have u a idea how i can check also the value?
 'arr = [{key1: searchedValue}, {key1:1}, {key1: 2}, {key2: date}, {key2: date2}, {key3: "string"} ]' now i want an array with object with key1: searchedValue (this value i want to search), key2: date, key2: date2, key3. –

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of objects and that those objects have a single key each, you can create a main dictionary to store all the keys found in the child objects. If the key is already present it ignores the new value, preserving the first one found

```
// create an object to store the unique ids
const dict = {};

// for each element of the array, take the first key found and use it as a key in the dict
filter.forEach(element => {
    const childKey = Object.keys(element)[0];
    if(!Object.hasOwnProperty(dict,childKey)){
        dict[childKey] = element;
    }
})

// now get the values from the dict
const result = Object.values(dict);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sounds good in theory but OP's expected results are to get the first occurrence but this overwrite approach returns last occurence

Comment: correct. edited

Answer (score 0):

Okay, according to your description your can do it this way:

This is your list `filter`

```
 const filter = [
  { key1: 'stringReq' },
  { key1: '1' },
  { key1: '2' },
  { key1: '3' },
  { key1: 'someString' },
  { key2: 'stringReq' },
  { key2: '5' },
  { key2: '6' },
  { key2: '7' },
  { key3: 'string' }
];
```

Your first use its `filter()` method in order to remove all objects whos value is not longer than 1.

```
// remove all entries that are 1 character long
const step1 = filter.filter(element => {
  const outerArray = Object.entries(element)[0];
  if (outerArray[1]) {
    return outerArray[1].length > 1;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Next you remove duplicate key names by adding all objects into a map with the field name as `key`. Because a map will accept each key only once. Dups will be droped and not added.

```
// remove duplicates
const map: Map<string, any> = new Map<string, any>();

filter.forEach(element => {
  const outerArray = Object.entries(element)[0];
  if (outerArray[0]) {
    map.set(outerArray[0], element);
  }
});
```

Finally you turn the map back into a list and that's it.

```
const final = Array.from(map);

console.log(final);
```